# How to solve below logic, using sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have 3 columns in my table: `col1`, `col2` and `col3`.

```
col2 is having (1,      0,   2,   3,   4,   0,   1,   3) 
col3 is having (1234,1023,1025,1032,1234,1013,1325,1332)
```

I have to get `col1` values as

```
(1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1013,1013,1013)
```

The logic is I have to get `col3` value for `col1` until the same number repeated in column two.

Please give me any suggestion to solve this.

Comment: the logic you gave to get `col1` values doesnt make sense. Please explain in bit more that why the value in `col1` is `1234` for first 5 rows.

Comment: But the rows in a table are unordered. You need some kind of sequential column too.

Comment: atleast show output desire."I have to get col3 value for col1 until the same number repeated in column two." this is not clear.re-explain.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `col2` has counts and `col3` has values, although your sample data doesn't really make this clear.  One way to do what you want is to use a numbers table, so here is a method:

```
with numbers as (
      select row_number() over (order by (select null)) as n
      from masterl.spt_values
     )
select t.col2
from t join
     numbers n
     on t.col3 <= n.n;
```

If you prefer a solution that doesn't depend on an undocumented system table:

```
with numbers as (
      select 1 as n, max(col2) as maxn
      from t
      union all
      select n + 1, maxn
      from numbers
      where n < max
     )
select t.col2
from t join
     numbers n
     on t.col3 <= n.n
option (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding an `IDENTITY` column to your table, you can do this as below:

```
ALTER TABLE t
ADD ColID int IDENTITY(1,1)
```

Or by creating a new table to ensure the data order is correct:

```
CREATE TABLE t (ColID int IDENTITY(1,1), Col1 int, Col2 int, Col3 int)
```

To answer the question, I need to use the table with the identity column so first insert the data..

```
INSERT t (Col2, Col3)
VALUES (1,1234),
    (0,1023),
    (2,1025),
    (3,1032),
    (4,1234),
    (0,1013),
    (1,1325),
    (3,1332),
    (5,1523),
    (4,1234)
```

Then, using a common table expression `cte` you can produce results for column one that only change to the new column three value if the value in column two is found in the data above, when ordered by the identity column:

```
;WITH cte as (
    SELECT ColID, 
        row_number() over (partition by Col2 order by ColID) count2,
        col2,
        col3
    FROM t
    )

SELECT t1.ColID, t2.Col3 Col1, t1.Col2, t1.Col3
FROM (
    SELECT c1.ColID,
        c1.Col2,
        c1.Col3,
        MAX(c2.ColID) ValColID
    FROM cte c1
    LEFT JOIN cte c2 ON c2.ColID <= c1.ColID AND (c2.count2 > 1 OR c2.ColID = 1)
    GROUP BY c1.ColID,c1.Col2,c1.Col3
    ) t1
INNER JOIN cte t2 ON t1.ValColID = t2.ColID
```